# Multiple parsing files with menhir

Tags: ocaml, menhir

I'm trying to have two different parsers with different entry points.

I have the following project hierarchy:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── dune
│   ├── lexer.mll
│   ├── main.ml
│   ├── parser.messages
│   ├── parser.mly
│   └── test_parser.mly
├── dune-project
├── program.opam
└── test
```

`lexer.mll`

```
{
  open Parser
  exception Error of string
}

rule token = parse
| [' ' '\t'] { token lexbuf }
| '\n' { EOL }
| ['0'-'9']+ as i { INT (int_of_string i) }
| '+' { PLUS }
| eof { exit 0 }
| _   { raise Exit }
```

`parser.mly`

```
%token <int> INT
%token PLUS
%token EOL

%left PLUS

%start <int> main

%%

main:
| e = expr EOL
    { e }

%public expr:
| i = INT { i }
| e1 = expr PLUS e2 = expr { e1 + e2 }
```

and `dune`

```
(ocamllex
 (modules lexer))

(menhir
 (modules parser)
 (flags --table)
)

(executable
 (name main)
 (public_name program)
 (libraries menhirLib)
)

(rule
 (targets parser_messages.ml)
 (deps parser.messages parser.mly)
 (action  (with-stdout-to %{targets} (run menhir --compile-errors %{deps}))))
```

This works perfectly (the parser.messages has been generated by `menhir --list-errors bin/parser.mly > bin/parser.messages` and is not really important)

However, I'd like to have a second parser that uses some rules defined in `parser.mly` and according to [http://gallium.inria.fr/~scherer/tmp/menhir-manual/main.html#sec23](http://gallium.inria.fr/%7Escherer/tmp/menhir-manual/main.html#sec23) it should be possible but I guess I'm doing it wrong:

`test_parser.mly`

```
%start <int> test

%%

test:
| el = separated_nonempty_list(COMMA, expr) EOL
    { List.fold_left (+) 0 e }
```

And in my dune file I added:

```
(menhir
 (modules parser test_parser)
 (merge_into test_parser)
 (flags --table))


(rule
 (targets test_parser_messages.ml)
 (deps test_parser.messages test_parser.mly)
 (action  (with-stdout-to %{targets} (run menhir --compile-errors %{deps}))))
```

But when I `dune build`:

```
❯ dune build
File "test_parser.mly", line 6, characters 21-25:
Error: expr is undefined.
File "bin/test_parser.mly", line 7, characters 27-28:
Error: Unbound value e
```

`expr` is preceded by `%public` in parser.mly so I thought I could use it from `test_parser.mly`. Can this feature only be used with a common entry point and different producing rules?